# How to make BLE Synchronous in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

My peripheral mode android app has problems connecting and then disconnecting. 
I have been investigating and it has been suggested that android ble does not work well async.
Does anyone have an example of a ble message queuing system for BLE in android?

Comment: What do you mean with does not work well async? If you have multiple things to do (reads / writes), just wait for the callback and then do your next thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a look at the github from Nordic Semiconductor, they provide a project which is probably what you need. It is a queuing system for GATT operations:
https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/puck-central-android